# Algebraic data types outside of functional languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

Which languages that are not solely functional have algebraic data
types (or something similar) and pattern matching? I'm also interested in multi-paradigm languages - I know that Ocaml and F# are ML dialects with OO added, so they inherit the algebraic data types from ML.

They can be kind-of emulated using `enum`s and `union`s (as in C, C++, ...more?), but this soon gets cumbersome and ugly, and the compiler can't warn you if you forget a case in your pattern matching or (much more propable, and much more dangerous) when accessing the union "in wrong ways", i.e. you ask for a field of a `Left` value when it's actually a `Right` value (what you get then is a meaningless reinterpretation of the bits that happen to be there).

I've heard that [Pascal has something like tagged unions](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Variant-Records.html) and the [Cyclone language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone_%28programming_language%29) supports tagged unions, too. Wikipedia also mentions Ada and Algol. Any other languages?

(In case you never heard of algebraic data types, you can read [an Answer to "What is 'Pattern Matching' in functional languages?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502787) for an excellent introduction).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Scala, you'd usually use `case class`es to emulate the algebraic data types as found in true-blue functional languages like ML and Haskell.

For example, following F# code (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx)):

```
type Shape =
| Circle of float
| EquilateralTriangle of double
| Square of double
| Rectangle of double * double

let area myShape =
    match myShape with
    | Circle radius -> Math.PI * radius * radius
    | EquilateralTriangle s -> (sqrt 3.0) / 4.0 * s * s
    | Square s -> s * s
    | Rectangle (h, w) -> h * w
```

can be roughly translated to Scala as follows:

```
sealed abstract class Shape
case class Circle(radius: Float) extends Shape
case class EquilateralTriangle(side: Double) extends Shape
case class Square(side: Double) extends Shape
case class Rectangle(height: Double, width: Double) extends Shape

def area(myShape: Shape) = myShape match {
  case Circle(radius) => math.Pi * radius * radius
  case EquilateralTriangle(s) => math.sqrt(3.0) / 4.0 * s * s
  case Square(s) => s * s
  case Rectangle(h, w) => h * w
}
```

The `sealed` keyword above is used to have the compiler warn you in case you forget any `case` in the `match` expression.

Answer (score 11):

In Mozilla's [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/) language, algebraic data types and pattern matching are important concepts. The syntax is also fairly nice. Consider the following simple program:

```
static PI: f32 = 3.14159;

enum Shape {
    Circle(f32),
    Rectangle(f32, f32),
    Point
}

fn area(shape: Shape) -> f32 {
    match shape {
        Point                    => 0.0
        Circle(radius)           => PI * radius * radius,
        Rectangle(width, height) => width * height,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let radius = 4.0;
    let circle = Circle(radius);
    let area = area(circle);
    println!("The area of a circle with radius {} is {}", radius, area);
}
```

Comment: The syntax is also fairly nice - yes, except for the curly braces salad and the semicolons.

Comment: @Malcolm I want to downvote your comment ;)   ---rarely is excessive noise helpful, the braces are not even informative of what block they close! The old style of if..fi or do..od  or beginX...endX at least is informative, with braces we tend to end up with a staircase that takes space and is completely unhelpful for readability..

Comment: With automatic code formatting, they are informative. To determine which brace corresponds with a block, all one must do is look up the page in a vertical line.

Regardless of the style, there's cognitive overhead with understanding where scope begins and ends. If one uses "beginX/endX", then one must name all scopes and remember all of the scopes by name to navigate a piece of code.

This is what I see as adding noise -- additional cognitive overhead (naming scopes) without any additional benefit.

Comment: I was coming around to the idea of using keywords to create code blocks (like if, fi, begin, end) until looking at some Ada code. Curly braces have the advantage of not adding to character noise. When reading code, not only do we want our code to be clearly defined in some hierarchy (its why we indent), we also want our focus to be on whats created, not a bunch of begin/end/procedure/etc.

Comment: The problem with many curly bracketed languages is that languages employing them encourage long functions with many nested control features. Instead, the language should support things like first class functions, type inference (on function returns and params), etc. to encourage shorter functions.

Answer (score 8):

The logic programming language Mercury calls them [discriminated unions](http://www.mercury.cs.mu.oz.au/information/comparison_with_haskell.html). The constraint language CHR, embedded in Prolog, [has them](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%277.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/practical.html%27%29%29#chr_type/1) too, but there they are entirely optional, general Prolog terms being the default type.

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea of logic languages, so I propably wouldn't have learned this myself.

Comment: Both are research languages. The LP community has been borrowing a lot from its FP cousins.

Answer (score 6):

Erlang has a dynamic type system, so it doesn't provide any of the guarantees you cite, but Erlang code does tend to look like the product of an algebraic type system:

```
count([]) -> 0;
count([H|T]) -> 1 + count(T).

length({rect, X, Y}) -> math:sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
length({polar, R, _A}) -> R.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that [Whiley](http://whiley.org/) would qualify.
Whiley has record types (.ie. product) and type unions (i.e. sum), hence.

Matching seems to be possible on type only, i.e. you can ask if a value with union type is one of the types in the union and then the value is "re-typed" and you can access the fields of the type you checked for.