# foreach and case statements in scala together. What is this structure called?

Tags: scala

I have a method like this:

```
def close(): Unit = {
    things.foreach {
      case (attr1, attr2) =>
        File.<do_something>(attr1, attr2)
    }
  }
```

What kind of structure is this? I know it's iterating through all the `things` which is a map if `<attr1, attr2>`. Can I access the thing itself?
What if I also wanted to pattern match on the class/type of the `thing`. How can I do this?

Comment: Is <attr1, arrr2> a tuple or a key value pair ? and are they option or what is their type ?

Comment: things is a `Map[attr1, attr2]`

Comment: Got it and what is the type of attr1 and attr2 ?

Comment: let's just say they are both custom classes. Say `attr1` is a `class1` and `attr2` is `class2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`foreach` is a method which takes a function `f: A => U` as an argument.

```
  @inline final override def foreach[U](f: A => U) {
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      f(these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
  }
```

Example below

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foreach { elem => println(s"my elem is $elem") }
my elem is 1
my elem is 2
my elem is 3
```

**Now, nice thing about scala is that you can "pattern match" based on value of element. Think of it like `if else` but also with capability of deconstructing your input. (*read about [patmat in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502787/432903)*)**

```
scala> List(1, "data", 3).foreach { 
         case elem: String => println(s"my elem is $elem") 
         case _ => println("something else")
       }
something else
my elem is data
something else
```

**The second example is whats happening in your example. you are pattern matching each element to `case (attr1, attr2)`**, meaning each element is deconstructed to `(attr1, attr2)`

**More example,**

```
scala> Map(1 -> "order 1", 2 -> "order 2", 3 -> "order 3").foreach { 
            case (key, value) => println(value)
       }
order 1
order 2
order 3

scala> List((1, "order 1"), (2, "order 2"), (3, "order 3")).foreach { 
            case (key, value) => println(value)
       }
order 1
order 2
order 3
```

Without "pattern match" you could simply provide a function,

```
scala> Map(1 -> "order 1", 2 -> "order 2", 3 -> "order 3").foreach { 
             keyValue => println(keyValue._2)
       }
order 1
order 2
order 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is applying an anonymous function which has two arguments to every element in `things`.

In the case that `things` is a `Map[A, B]`, it will apply `File.<do_something>` to the key and value of each pair in the map assuming `<do_something>`'s first argument is of type `A` and the second argument is of type `B`.